# How to use macro for undefined reference

Tags: c, gcc, macros, linker, undefined

I have C code that compile staticly with `.a` file via GCC .

In c code I use functions that implement in .a file .

How can I do macro (in c code) that use like if else if this function is defined in `.a` file or not , for example , if function `a` is undefined I want to use function `b`:

```
# IF_A_UNDEFINED
b()
#ELSE
a()
#ENDIF
```

Is that passible?

Comment: No. It is utterly impossible the way you describe it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala so what is the better way to do that in C code when compiled staticly? in gcc compile line ?

Comment: Maybe [weak symbols](http://www.valvers.com/programming/c/gcc-weak-function-attributes/)?

Answer (score 0):

3 answers: No, No, Maybe (it may not be what you are looking for)

Short answer, no.

Longer answer, but TLDR, still no. For the most part, errors on compile cannot be ignored. For sure, the use of an undeclared parameter cannot be ignored, and if you are looking for a function that doesn't exist, well, you can't reference it without a declared function name.

Finally, You could declare the function like so:
`void functionA() __attribute__((weak, alias("functionB")));`

`void    functionB() { printf"Hello World\n"; }`

Comment: thank you about your time .  if I will do that if functionA will not exsit in `.a` file the linker will serach functionB  instead?